# How do I refer to a method overload using a dynamic type in C# XML comments?

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, documentation

I am trying to use the `<see>` tag in C#'s XML documentation.  The problem is that I have two method overloads that use the `dynamic` keyword. So, I have something like the following: 

`DoSomething(Func{dynamic,dynamic},object[])`

I keep getting a compiler warning that my cref attribute cannot be resolved.  I've tried and failed to fix this. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `object` instead - that's the *real* compile-time type, at the IL level, so:

```
<see cref="DoSomething(Func{object,object},object[])" />
```

Will give that a try to check it works myself...